# How to Disable button for some days

Tags: java, android

I need help..

I have two classes Class1.java and Class2.java. In Class1 one button(PAY) is there to goto Class2. Class2 is Billing Activity and it has one button to go back to Class1.
Button Color should changed when Billing is completed for current month. I want Class1 button to be disable from current date to 1st of next month and enable every 1st of month..

I have tried but havn't got anything...

This is my code..

Class1.java

```
Intent i=new Intent(Class1.this,Class2.class);<br>
startActivityForResult(i, 123);


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){        
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);<br>
    if (requestCode == 123) {
        pay.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this,
                R.color.Green), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        pay.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Class2.java

```
Intent i1=new Intent(Class2.this,Class1.class);<br>
setResult(123,i1);<br>
```

Comment: button.setEnabled(billing.isCompleted()) ... something like that

Comment: What is the current result which you are getting? The button is still enabled after `onActivityResult()` is executed?

Comment: you need to save the month that billing is completed then use the calendar to get the current month and see if billing was completed or not. Then disable the button based on that

Comment: Recommend you look at this article: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: You can can keep two variables in shared preference one for days and one for date you start counting days then match preference date with current date and find difference if difference match with your preference days then enable button else don't.

Answer (score 0):

Class2.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("isBillCompleted", true);
setResult(123, intent);
```

Class1.java

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode ==123 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        boolean isCompleted = data.getBooleanExtra("isBillCompleted", false);
        if (isCompleted){
            pay.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            pay.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to add `@Override` ano

Comment: Thanks for response sir...These work well till i stop the app after restart the app the button is enable with the prev button color..

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to the android technology look after [Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example).

Get the current time in milliseconds and convert it into the days minus the previous billing time if the difference is more than 30 days enable the button or keep it disabled.
Once the billing is done reset the BILLED_ON to the current date.

```
long timeDifference = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(System.currentTimeMillis()) - sharedPreferences.getLong("TIMING", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(System.currentTimeMillis()));
button.setEnabled(timeDifference > 30);
```

Hope it helps.